# How to free one of the index of an array pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Suppose I have pointer array;

```
int *x;
```

when I free one of the index of x, other indices are unavailable also.

```
free(x[4]);
int k = x[3]; // gives segmentation error. If do not free no error.
```

Is there any way to free one of the specified index of an pointer array?

Comment: That code will not compile. Please post a real example!

Comment: how did you allocate the memory? It seems that you have an array of int, not an array of pointer so you can only dealloc the array itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code example, you are trying to free something that is not a pointer type. You can only do `free(x)` and that is only after you `malloc'd` it. Basically, you are doing something like:

```
 int a;
 free(a);
```

If you want to be able to free array elements, then your array has to be of `int**` type. Be careful to malloc them again or set them properly after that, too.

Comment: @Erogol: you must only free the exact pointer you allocated with malloc.